# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el borde un elemento?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que quiero hacer es saber que elemento de mi formulario tiene un borde rojo y el que lo tenga al cerra mi formulario o guardar o cancelar la acción, ese mismo que estaba en rojo se cambie a un color de borde en blanco.

entonces me gustaria saber como identifico que elemento tiene una tonalidad diferente al resto de mis objetos del formulario y en base a ello aplicar una acción.

Tengo este breve codigo:

```
 alert($("#txtNombreP").css("border-color"));
```

Me aparece como una alerta en blanco, pero si pongo otras propiedades si me trae su valor, no se si lo escribo mal.

Comment: La ultima actualización a tu pregunta incluye una nueva pregunta. Podrías formularla en una nueva pregunta ya que se trata de otro tema diferente. Por otro lado, si alguna respuesta dada te sirvió, marcala como aceptada

Comment: @Rene Limon, ya lo realice gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponiendo, por que no pones ningun codigo, tienes un elemento y el boder de este es una clase en CSS, llamado borde-rojo y otro borde-azul

Entonces

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  
  if( $('#elemento').hasClass('borde-rojo') ){
    console.log('El elemento tiene borde rojo así que lo cambiaré a borde azul');
    // Y lo reemplazamos por el borde azul
    $('#elemento').removeClass('borde-rojo').addClass('borde-azul');
  }

});
```

```css
.borde-rojo {
    border-color: red;
    border-style: double;
}

.borde-azul {
    border-color: blue;
    border-style: double;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elemento" class="borde-rojo">Hola</div>
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) que devuelve el estilo computado del elemento.

Ejemplo:

```js
var computed = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('div1'));
console.log('Div1 border-color:', computed['border-color']);

var computed = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('div2'));
console.log('Div2 border-color:', computed['border-color']);
```

```css
.borde-rojo {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}
.borde-verde {
  border: 2px solid #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="borde-rojo">
Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500
</div>
<div id="div2" class="borde-verde">
Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

El border es un caso especial:

```js
alert( "Izquierda-> color:"+$("div").css("border-left-color"));
alert( "Derecha->color:"+$("div").css("border-right-color"));
alert( "Arriba->color:"+$("div").css("border-top-color"));
alert( "Abajo->color:"+$("div").css("border-bottom-color"));
```

```css
div{
  border-color: red green blue yellow;
  border-style: dashed solid double dotted;
  border-width: 2px 10px 4px 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 hola
</div>
```

porque tiene 4 **lados**:

- left
- right
- top
- bottom

y **propiedades**:

- style
- width
- color
- etc...

Para acceder a ellos debes acceder con la siguiente estructura:

```
border-[lado]-[propiedad]
border-left-color
border-top-style
// y así sucesivamente...
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes iterar a los elementos, y preguntar sobre las propiedades de border
con `if($(this).css('border-right-style')=="solid"){` ejemplo:

```js
var elementos=$('#formulario > div');
  elementos.each(function(key) {
   if($(this).css('border-right-style')=="solid"){
   console.log("el", this.id, "tiene border solid");
    }
});
```

```css
#hijo1{
 border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formulario">
  <div id="hijo1">
  </div>
  <div id="hijo2">
  </div>
</div>
```